# Where can I get the specifications regarding utility pole erection such as depth, muffing etc.?

Tags: power-engineering

I believe that there will be a engineering body who publishes specifications of various engineering work. 
Particularly, I'm looking for specifications for pole erections such as depth of the pole below ground, height at which cross-arm is fixed, minimum clearance, sag etc.

Comment: _"national body"_, hm, let me take out my crystal ball.. I sense.. you live in.. Botswana! Hopefully someone from Botswana can answer.

Comment: LOL. Feel free to edit.

Comment: @user3290439 No, you're supposed to make an edit and mention in which country you're interested in.

Comment: Edited. No specific to country now.

Comment: Specific to country.  In the UK, for example, you would need to talk to your local Distribution Network Operator.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity in the question. But this little conversation helps a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only are these requirements country-specific they are also urban/rural They are also HV level specific

e.g. high density and traffic intersections require greater safety margins.
UHV towers require stiffer requirements than HV poles.

Here is a rural USDA agriculture spec.
[www.rd.usda.gov/files/UEP_Bulletin_1728F-810.pdf](http://www.rd.usda.gov/files/UEP_Bulletin_1728F-810.pdf)
To provide general construction requirements for representative wood pole structures and assemblies for 34.5 through 69 kV transmission lines.

Comment: Thanks Tony. I'm able to find the right document, similar to what you suggested for reference.